# Add items to sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I would use jqueru ui and sortable, but I have some silly mistake and I can not change the item added by the "entry-add" item.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7p0w1gpe/3/

```
$(function() {
  $('.test').sortable({
    connectWith: ".test"    
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the connectWith to the already present divs with the test class. When you add a new div with the class test and make it sortable, you are forgetting to also add the connectWith.

I've added it in the fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/ksxLymox/

```
  $(function() {
$('.test').sortable({
  connectWith: ".test",

}).disableSelection();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.add-done', function() {
    $('<div id="sortable1" class="test connectedSortable"><a class="ui-state-default">Item 1</a></div>').insertBefore('.add-done').sortable({connectWith: ".test"});
    console.log("add");
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.entry-add', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.test').append('<a href="#">new items</a>').sortable({connectWith: ".test"});
  });
```

To make your code even better you could reuse a function to make a div sortable.